# What is the exact relation between a full rank matrix and its determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

I would like to know in particular whether a full rank matrix necessarilly has a determinant equal to/different from zero. Also, would the answer change based on the matrix being squared or not?

Comment: A full-rank square matrix has *invertible* determinant—in particular (and equivalently, if we work over a field), non-0.  A non-square matrix (regardless of rank) does not have a determinant.

Comment: A full rank matrix can be triangularized with non-zero entries along the diagonal.

Comment: @user170231, I like that formalisation.  I never thought of that fact as a 'non-square' generalisation of full-rank implying non-0 determinant, but it fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full ranked matrix has a determinant different than zero. Squaring the matrix will still give us a full ranked matrix with determinant different than zero. This is due to the fact that a matrix has determinant other than zero iff it is invertible, and that is iff the matrix is full ranked.

Comment: So, "full rankness" and invertibility are equivalent property? Thus, non-zero determinat implies them both? Did I get it right?

Comment: I had the impression that 'squared' in @user98139 's original post was meant to be 'square'—that is, a condition on the size of the matrix, not an algebraic operation to be performed on it.

Comment: Also, @user98139, it is important that (in addition to working with square matrices) you are working over a field; otherwise a matrix can have a non-0 determinant but not be invertible.  (Consider, for example, $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.)  Having full rank is equivalent to being invertible, and both imply that the determinant is non-$0$ (for square matrices over any (commutative) coefficient ring); both are *implied* by non-$0$ determinant (for square matrices over a (commutative) field).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In linear algebra a lot of seeming different properties are equivalent, such as non-0 determinant and a matrix being full ranked. When I first learned linear algebra we had a theorem that stated about 20 different properties that are equivalent to invertibility.

Comment: @LSpice: you are right, I mean nxn. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't realize it! Would this change the answers?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant squaring the matrix. The determinant is not defined for mxn matrices where m is not equal to n.

Comment: @user98139, yes, in the sense that one can't even speak of the determinant of a non-square matrix (and that, over a field, no such matrix is invertible).  In this sense probably [@user170231](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811123/what-is-the-exact-relation-between-a-full-rank-matrix-and-its-determinant#comment3701206_1811123)'s comment on your post is the best you can say.

Comment: Ok, thank you both very much! Let me ask you just another small question. For a square (nxn) matrix, showing that the determinant is non-zero and showing that all the columns are linearly independent are equivalent ways to prove full rank?

Comment: Each one is equivalent to full rank. No need to show both.

Comment: @Noam Thanks again!